# Node.js utility module structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

While working on many differente Node.js projects, I began having common code that I want to move out in a new Node.js package in order to not rewrite the same code multiple times. I've a new Node.js module and I'm using it in my projects using `npm link`.

Now, I'm a bit confused as to how to structure this common library in order to properly modularize it. This is what I have right now in my common library:

```
// "my-common-lib"'s app.js

module.exports = {
    math: require("./math/mathLib"),
    network: require("./network/networkLib")
};
```

--

```
//mathLib.js 
exports.pi = 3.14;
```

This works, I can do the following in another node.js project:

```
var commonLibrary = require("my-common-lib");
var commonMath = commonLibrary.Math;

console.log("Pi: " + commonMath.pi);
```

While this solves the issue, I would prefer something similar to how lodash does it:

```
var commonMath = require("my-common-lib/math");

console.log("Awesome pi: " + commonMath.pi);
```

I can't quite figure out how lodash does it, and I would [definitely like to avoid having a humongous main js file](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js).

TL;DR I want to modularize a node.js module so I can require submodules (`require("my-common-lib\myCommonMathLib")`), how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lodash does it with a dedicated modular build. Look at the [ES6 build](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/3.9.3-es) for example. Every "sub-project" has a dedicated module, in a dedicated '.js' file. The aggregating file (lodash.js) simply imports all other modules.

If you want the nice `lib/module` convention, simply have a your lib.js file (aggregator) at the top level, next to a directory by the same name where all internal modules are kept.

Another option for the `require("lib")` part is to have a `"main": "lib.js"` configuration in your `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `lodash/array` for example, LoDash has an `array.js` file, with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  'chunk': require('./array/chunk'),
  'compact': require('./array/compact'),
```

So you can easily have `math.js` inside your main folder, which has something like:

```
module.exports = {
   pi: 3.14
   // OR
   pi: require('./math/pi'); // and have file pi.js inside math folder
}
```

This way you can use it as a short:

```
var math = require('my-common-lib/math');
math.pi; // 3.14
```